# Open dropdown in DevTools which only works if the tab is active

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have an issue where I try to open/activate a dropdown/select programatically using DevTools. This doesn't sound hard, but I have a case now where I cannot get it to work properly. The site (ReactJs) looks as follows (url is in the screenshot too!)

[image]

That dropdown is a custom dropdown, and I can open it programmatically as follows

```
setTimeout(() => {
   document.querySelector('.css-ackcql').dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown', { bubbles: true}));
}, 3000);
```

Important is that after you execute this code you have to focus the tab (click somewhere on the page), otherwise nothing will happen (thats why I have the `setTimeout`). Apparently, when DevTools is active (because you execute the code) the tab is not, which seems to result in an inactive website.

My question is, is there a way to activate the dropdown without activating the tab manually?

For example, I tried the following

```
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('focus', { bubbles: true }));
document.querySelector('.css-ackcql').dispatchEvent(new Event('mousedown', { bubbles: true}));
```

It didn't work. I tried this because I noticed the following:

[image]

It is listening for `focus` and `blur`. But that doesn't seem to be the case (or I do something wrong). I also checked `document.hidden`, but that property doesn't really reflect that `active` status of a tab, unfortunately

Is there anyone who has experience with this kind of behaviour and knows how this works?

Update: I just noticed that this whole exercise doesnt seem to work too on a normal select element, weird

---

Comment: Press Ctrl-Shift-P to open commands palette, type `emfoc`, and select "Emulate focused page".

Comment: Very nice, didn't know that options. This solves the issue when using DevTools. How can something be achieved with the chrome extension (no devtools). Is there maybe a way to start chrome with a specific argument (--emfoc ?? [List of commandline switches](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)) I did find any :(